# Can (Eclipse) AST capture the LineCommet and BlockComment content?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I have recently tried the Eclipse AST (i.e., org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST and etc) to analyze java source codes. I encountered a problem when trying to capture the content of BlockComment and LineComment. Concretely, I used getCommentList function to obtain the node information of these two types of comment nodes. Although their node types are recognized, the comment.toString failed to return any meaningful content except "/* */" and "//".

The codes I used are provided as below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.BlockComment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.LineComment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Comment;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class run_visitor {
    public run_visitor(String path) throws IOException {
        // file content
        File fd = new File(path);
        String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(fd);
        
        // parser 
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setSource(content.toCharArray());
        
        // cu creation
        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
        
        kaixin_visitor visitor = new kaixin_visitor();
        cu.accept(visitor);
        
        List<Comment> commentLists = cu.getCommentList();
        for (Comment comment : commentLists) {
            if (comment instanceof BlockComment) {
                System.out.println("This is Block comment:" + comment.toString());
            } else if (comment instanceof LineComment) {
                System.out.println("This is Line comment:" + comment.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "demo.java";
        run_visitor vst = new run_visitor(path);
    }
}
```

So can anyone tell me if it is the internal feature of AST that cannot capture the string content of these two types of nodes, or, maybe I made a mistake in using any functions or procedures?

Some referred links are provided as follows:

1.http://help.eclipse.org/2021-06/index.jsp
2.https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/dom/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Comment` class just remembers the start and length of the comment, so if you want the actual comment text you get it from the original source using the `getStartPosition` and `getLength` methods of `Comment`.

```java
int startPos = comment.getStartPosition();
int endPos = startPos + comment.getLength();
String text = content.substring(startPos, endPos);
```